# Intercept error messages?

Tags: errors, editors, logging

Is it possible to override error messages?

The latex log sometimes makes it hard to tell, what file was being parsed when an error or warning was reported. Files are denotes by `(FILENAME ...)` in the log, but warning messages may contain closing and opening parentheses too, throwing off log parsers as implemented in TexStudio. The `-c-style-errors` (Miktex) doesn't help either, since the error messages are then incomplete and in a format unknown to the parsers.

I wanted to use the `currfile` package to wrap such a `(FILENAME ...)` construct around each warning and error message to ensure correct attribution, but I couldn't find a method that would affect errors like

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \nosuchcommand
```

or warnings about overfull boxes.

Is it possible to override those messages, or are they hardcoded in the engine?

Comment: It's hardcoded but there are two styles, try `pdflatex --file-line-error`  then it will put the filename as well as the line number (although that's probably the same as the miktex option you mentioned)

Comment: I was using the equivalent (?) option `-c-style-errors` (miktex) in such unclear cases to track down the issue. Sadly it doesn't help with improving editor-integrated error reporting, since the log parser assumes the standard `! Message ... l.LINENUM` format.

Comment: you could raise a functionality request with your editor developers that they support that style (which was specifically added to make their lives easier:-)

Comment: [I did just now.](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/325) Sadly, at least on MikTeX, the option doesn't affect warnings and causes omission of the context-information included in normal error messages, so I kind of expect this to receive a "Won't fix" reply.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle [Confirmed...](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/325#issuecomment-447992703) Since warnings are rather important for final production, `--file-line-error` really only becomes worth it for editors, when warnings are covered too, [but that seems to be a hard issue](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/230). There's also, with Miktex, the issue [that `--file-line-error` results in *less* useful error messages](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/181), as all details are omitted.